# NetLogo forces on an agent

Tags: netlogo

**Given:** Consider force-x and force-y as the force x and y components respectively on the agent,

**Aim**:you want turtle to move one of 8 neighboring patches depending force-x and force-y (Normal mechanics)

**Requirement:** minimum if-else statements to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were sure that your forces were not big enough to push the turtle past one of the neighboring patches, you could simply use [`move-to`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#move-to) and [`patch-at`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-at), and ask your turtle to:

```
move-to patch-at force-x force-y
```

But perhaps your forces are bigger than that, and you still want to limit the possible moves to the neighbors. Then you can use a combination of [`min-one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-at) and [`distance`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#distance) to achieve that:

```
let p patch-at force-x force-y
move-to min-one-of neighbors [ distance p ]
```

But then again, maybe you also want to account for the possibility that the forces are not big enough to push the turtle all the way a neighbor. If that is the case, you can use [`patch-set`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-set) to add the current patch (given by [`patch-here`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-here)) to the set of possible destinations:

```
let p patch-at force-x force-y
move-to min-one-of (patch-set patch-here neighbors) [ distance p ]
```